# Inheritance from no polymorphic class

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor, new-operator

Let's suppose I want to create a wrapper over a class, but that class has no virtual destructor (it isn't polymorphic at all).

```
class wrapper : public class_type
{
   /* No data members */

public:
   using class_type::class_type;

   // Some methods personalized. Or extra methods. No interest
   // in polymorphism.
};
```

However, if I create a pointer:

```
void f(std::unique_ptr<class_type> to_me)
{ /**/ }

f(std::unique_ptr<class_type>(new wrapper));
```

when the `std::unique_ptr` life ends, the `wrapper`'s destructor is not called, but, since `wrapper` has a trivial destructor and there's nothing to destroy or cleaning up, because it has no own data members, what does the standard says about that situation? Is it UB?

Comment: Yes, it's UB.  You don't need to `move` the expression `std::unique_ptr<class_type>(new wrapper)`, which is already an rvalue.

Comment: That's right. Fixed. You know, the habit.

Comment: It's not a very good idea, to say the least.

Comment: @n.m. Yes I know. I don't like it too. I was just curious about what happen in the case where the derived class has nothing to destroy.

Comment: The standard makes no exceptions for classes that add no members. UB is UB is UB. What else is there to know?